# iOS - FMDB database insert

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite, fmdb

To insert data into a database using sqlite requires copying of the database to make it writable. So I have this method in my class which every suggestion I've seen over stack overflow and many other sites:

```
-(void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded 
{  
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.db"];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (success) return;
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.db"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

}
```

Of course I have this next codes to access my database:

```
FMDatabase *db; = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"db"]];
if (![db open]) {
    NSLog(@"Error!");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Database opened!!");
}

[self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
[db executeUpdate:@"Insert into user (name, phone, comment) values(?, ?, ?)", @"Name1", @"13548", @"This is a comment", nil];
NSLog(@"Inserted");

FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM user"];
while ([s next]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [s stringForColumn:@"comment"]);
}
```

Now, I have a few questions:

1. The insertion code worked perfectly in the simulator when being executed/ran. However, this didn't have an effect to the real sample.db which I concluded it must have a writable copy somewhere in the hard drive of my mac. That is acceptable. But when I ran these code on the iphone, it somewhat didn't recognize my `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` method and gave this error:  `Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement > (8: attempt to write a readonly database)`. How do I make these codes work using FMDB?
2. When running on the iPhone, where would the be copied database located? After copied, does the iPhone use that database again even if not connected to my mac?

I cannot insert something when ran on the device. 
Please help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: 1. you can't edit/update/change files that are in your AppBundle you need to create the db in your document Directory.

Comment: yes, and i recommend to use FMDatabase or CoreData (event better ) with SQLite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are reading this, then I have the explanation to your problem.

1. If there is any file in **Resource Bundle**, then it is a READ-ONLY file. So, your database path to your resources directory is available for reading purposes only.
2. According to the code that you have written to copy the database, the database will be created in the your *application's document directory*. This path will be unaffected even when you remove your iPhone from your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

try this to insert in database

```
[db open];

FMResultSet *results = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT cms_desc FROM cms_media where cms_name=%@",@"name"];

NSString *str;

while([results next]) 

{

    str=[results stringForColumn:@"cms_desc"];
}

[results close];

[db close];
```

just drag and drop the .sqlite file in you project and reset you app in device

Comment: Thanks, but you're way too far my friend, way too far.